# MySQL SELECT statment with one DISTINCT field

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have a list of cars with each car having a `make` and `model` column. I would like to extract a list of unique make/model combinations from the list.

For example, there might be 3 x Audi A3 vehicles, one red, one blue etc. I would like the query to return that 'Audi A3' is a valid make/model regardless of how many times it appears.

Here was the query I tried:

```
SELECT make, DISTINCT model FROM bs_cars ORDER BY make, model ASC
```

I have tried to apply `DISTINCT` to `model` only as `make` would potentially have various models under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` option applies at the row level, there is no point selecting distinct values only from one column. This is why it stays before any expression that appears in the `SELECT` clause.

It removes the duplicate rows from the output, keeping a single instance of any pair (`make`, `model`) you have in the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT make, model
FROM bs_cars
ORDER BY make, model ASC
```

Check the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 2):

This will give you list of unique make/model combinations

```
SELECT DISTINCT make, model FROM bs_cars ORDER BY make, model ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The `distinct` keyword is applied once to the select list, not per field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT make, model FROM bs_cars ORDER BY make, model ASC
```