# SUM of a quantity column when using INNER JOIN and distinct/group by

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT( rentals.order_item_id ), reserved_date, product_id, quantity, order_id FROM `test_rentals` as rentals
    INNER JOIN `test_orderitemmeta` as orderitemmeta
    WHERE `reserved_date` = '2020-07-07'
    AND `product_id` = 109
    AND orderitemmeta.meta_key = 'returned'
    AND orderitemmeta.meta_value = 'yes'
```

This returns:

| order_item_id | reserved_date | product_id | quantity | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 134 | 2020-07-07 | 109 | 1 | 274 |
| 138 | 2020-07-07 | 109 | 1 | 276 |

The `test_orderitemmeta` table contains a unique `meta_id`, `order_item_id`, `meta_key` and `meta_value`, there can be multiple rows with the same order_item_id, the rentals table only has the `order_item_id` column to join these with.

I want the return to be a single row showing the reserved_date, product_id and the total quantity, I thought I could do this by using `SUM( quantity )` but this gives the result:

| order_item_id | reserved_date | product_id | SUM(quantity) | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 134 | 2020-07-07 | 109 | 16 | 274 |

I think this is using the total rows which would be available before the `DISTINCT`?

I've also considered removing the `DISTINCT( rentals.order_item_id )` and using a `GROUP BY rentals.order_item_id` on the end of the query but this does not give the result I am looking for either.

How can I get the result to be a single row with the total quantity like this:

| reserved_date | product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-07-07 | 109 | 2 |

Comment: Can you show us the exact result you want?

Comment: [`DISTINCT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) is not a function, it is a modifier of the `SELECT` clause and it applies to the entire row (it does not make sense otherwise). Also read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945165/4265352

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The `JOIN` without a condition (`ON ...`) produces all combinations of rows from the first table with rows from the second table. You need a condition to combine only the related rows from the two tables (i.e. the metadata rows that belong to the desired rental.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you the result you need :

```
SELECT reserved_date, product_id, SUM(quantity) as quantity
FROM `test_rentals` as rentals, `test_orderitemmeta` as orderitemmeta
WHERE `reserved_date` = '2020-07-07'
    AND `product_id` = 109
    AND orderitemmeta.meta_key = 'returned'
    AND orderitemmeta.meta_value = 'yes'
GROUP BY reserved_date, product_id
```

Comment: No - everything is fine with the columns but the quantity is 16 (which I think is occuring because there are 8 rows of test_orderitemmeta for each order_item_id)

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge There should be a condition on the `INNER JOIN` clause to filter only the metadata that belongs to the desired rental. You didn't specify anything about it in the query posted in the question.

Comment: @axiac i also saw that problem but i decided to leave it as it was in the question. Maybe he had a reason, i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

[`DISTINCT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) is not a function, it is a modifier of the `SELECT` clause and it applies to the entire row (it does not make sense otherwise). It does not help here.

The `JOIN` without a condition (`ON ...`) produces all combinations of rows from the first table with rows from the second table. You need a condition to combine only the related rows from the two tables (i.e. the metadata rows that belong to the desired rental).

Assuming that the table `test_orderitemmeta` contains a column named `rental_id` that links the metadata record to the rental record that owns the metadata, a query that produces the result you expect looks like:

```sql
SELECT r.reserved_date, r.product_id, SUM(r.quantity) AS quantity
FROM test_rentals AS r
INNER JOIN test_orderitemmeta AS m ON r.rental_id = m.rental_id
WHERE r.reserved_date = '2020-07-07'
  AND r.product_id = 109
  AND m.meta_key = 'returned'
  AND m.meta_value = 'yes'
GROUP BY r.product_id, r.reserved_date
```

Replace `rental_id` with the correct column name from your tables.

Comment: The test_orderitemmeta table contains a unique meta_id, order_item_id, meta_key and meta_value, there can be multiple rows with the same order_item_id, the rentals table only has the order_item_id column to join these with

Comment: You know why the question has been downvoted? Because it does not contain the needed information to be answered. All these pieces you write here and there in comments should be in the question. Together with the definitions of the two tables involved in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You will try this code get the result for you need:

```
    SELECT rentals.*, orderitemmeta.reserved_date, orderitemmeta.product_id, SUM(orderitemmeta.quantity) as quantity
    FROM `test_rentals` as rentals JOIN test_orderitemmeta as orderitemmeta on orderitemmeta.product_id = rentals.order_item_id 
WHERE orderitemmeta.reserved_date = '2020-07-07'
        AND orderitemmeta.product_id = 109
        AND orderitemmeta.meta_key = 'returned'
        AND orderitemmeta.meta_value = 'yes'
```